# when i unload my page embed my activex. activex don't destroy

Tags: activex, embed, skype, add-on

My MFC `ActiveX` is simple active. I make it by MFC `ActiveX` template of Visual Studio 2008.
i just add call show message dialog when `ActiveX` destroy to test.

```
CmfcActivexCtrl::~CmfcActivexCtrl()
{
    AfxMessageBox(_T("destroy"));
}
```

I open my page embed this `ActiveX`. After I navigate to other address.

1. if i disable skype-addon then message "destroy" display. ActiveX destroyed
2. if i enable skype-addon then message "destroy" don't display. ActiveX don't destroy.

I test in ie7 and ie8. it is bug of skype or bug of MFC. what is solution?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with the Skype plugin loaded, your ActiveX control is not getting unloaded until later.  Perhaps you should put all of your clean up in another event handler, like before close?